# unbale to run nexus image on local

Tags: docker, nexus

docker run -d -p 8081:8081 --name nexus -v /home/nexus-data:/nexus-data sonatype/nexus3:latest

docker --version
Docker version 20.10.10, build b485636

unable to get this command
/usr/share/maven/bin# curl http://localhost:8081
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8081: Connection refused

Comment: if you run docker container log CONTAINERID, you may read something like:
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /nexus-data/log/karaf.log (No such file or directory)

Read this thread:
https://github.com/sonatype/docker-nexus/issues/31

Comment: Anything in the nexus logs?